# How to set background-position-x with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm tired of setting `background-position-x` with IE, `$('.scroller').css('background-position-x', posX+'px');` is not woking, any other methods

```
var posX = $('.scroller').css('background-position');
    if(typeof(posX) === 'undefined')
    {
        posX = $(' .scroller').css('background-position-x');
    }
    posX = posX.split(" ",1);
    posX = parseInt(posX,10);

    posX = (posX > 100 ) ? 0 : posX+1;
    if(isIE()){
        $('.scroller').css('background-position-x', posX+'px');
    } else {
        $('.scroller').css('background-position', posX+'px center');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In IE8 standards mode, you have to call it "-ms-background-position-x".